# Problems converting Java math to C#

Tags: c#, math

Math is not my strong point by any means; I had to ask around quite a bit to get a working trigonometric function working in Java. However now I'm needing the same function; However moved to C#.

```
private static Position a = new Position(1,1);
private static Position b = new Position(1.5, 1.5);
public static float getAngle(Position me, Position target) {
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(target.getY() - me.getY(), target.getX() - me.getX()));
    if(angle < 0){
        angle += 360;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

Looking around it doesn't even seem like C# has a ToDegrees method, I've found the Atan2 method, but without the ToDegrees I'm completely lost.

Sorry if this is a really ridiculous question, but I'm horrible with math and don't understand all of the terminology.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to write your own methods to convert Radian To Degrees. It is a simple formula and seems that's why it is left out of the library.

> It can be a bit confusing at first which angle mode the C#.NET is using, but the answer is radians.

You will need to write math converters to achieve your conversions.

```
private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
   return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}

private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
   return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}
```

You can read this article for further help http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_net_angles.php

According to your example, it should be

```
public double getAngle(Vector2 me, Vector2 target) {
    return RadianToDegree(Math.Atan2(target.y - me.y, target.x - me.x));
}
```

Comment: Dear, using these with Math.Atan2(as in example) is returning an angle of `0.999906049801551` *Which should be 45.0* .   `Debug.Log("Angle: " + Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(Math.Atan2(b.y - a.y, b.x - a.x))));`

Comment: @Christian.tucker What are the values you are passing here? b.y, a.y, b.x and a.x?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yVVhw2Qr

Same as in my Java example. (Where the first value in the vector is X, and the second is Y)

Comment: @Christian.tucker This is because you are doing a Math.Cos before returning the angle. Updated the answer with your code corrected.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own `ToDegrees` method:

```
private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
   return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

For example:

```
double angle = DegreeToRadian(Math.Atan2(1.0,2.0));
```

For completeness, this is the reverse method:

```
private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
  return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}
```

You can also check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation which does a similar conversion.

Comment: Thanks going to try this.

Comment: For explanation: 1 circle = 360 degree = 2 pi (radian)

Comment: Is the proper term `DegreeToRadian` or `RadianToDegree`?

Comment: RadianToDegree is the correct term. Check the MSDN documentation in my answer for more details.

Comment: The following code: `  Vector2 a = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
  Vector2 b = new Vector2(1.5f, 1.5f);
  Debug.Log("Angle: " + Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(Math.Atan2(b.y - a.y, b.x - a.x))));` *returns* Angle: 0.999906049801551 *Which should be 45.0*

Comment: You need to use RadianToDegree.

Comment: @JacodeGroot - Even then the angle returned is ` 0.52532198881773`

Comment: Marking this correct as the link to the MSDN had the proper answer `  return Math.Atan2(target.y - me.y, target.x - me.x) * (180/Math.PI);` Please update the answer accordingly.

Comment: `Math.cos` expects the input in arc length (radians), `Math.atan2` gives its result in radians, so in plugging the two together there is no conversion in between required. The result with the given inputs should be `sqrt(0.5)` which is about `0.71`.